# Busquedas, Paginacion, tipo

Tags: paginación, busqueda

En algunas paginas cuando buscas algo aparece en la direccion **[www.url.com/celulares/smartphone_Desde_51](http://www.url.com/celulares/smartphone_Desde_51)**, en otras termina en **/?celulares&?busqueda=smartphone&?page=1** y en otras simplemente no aparece nada.
¿Por que sucede esto?

Comment: ¿Y la duda entonces cuál es?

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta corta sería que depende de cómo hayan programado dicho sistema de paginación o incluso el sitio web con su sistema de url amigables.

Pero aclarando un poco los 3 ejemplos que has dado, paso a explicar de manera breve para que sea mas claro.

Suponiendo que tenemos una página web de venta de artículos, donde el documento principal es `index.php`

Por el otro lado, podemos (o no) tener un archivo llamado `smartphones.php`

Bien, en tu primer ejemplo, con la url `www.url.com/celulares/smartphone_Desde_51` vemos una url amigable; mediante el archivo `.httacces`, o desde `php` por ejemplo, puedes modificar la url por motivos de `SEO` haciendo que no aparezcan los típicos `& ? =`

Un ejemplo muy resumido de ésto mediante `.httacces` podría ser asi:

```
RewriteRule ^celulares/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ smartphones.php?busqueda=$1&page=$2
```

Donde la url finalmente de cara al usuario se vería `www.url.com/celulares/smartphone/5`

Al nosotros ejecutar esa url, seria el equivalente a `www.url.com/smartphones.php?busqueda=smartphone&page=5`

Pero como podrás comprobar, es mucho mas sencillo de recordar la primera opción y eso a la hora del posicionamiento del sitio es importante.

Respecto a que a veces no aparece nada, podría ser por ejemplo, que se esté utilizando `javascript` dentro del propio `index.php` para hacer la consulta a `smartphones.php` (ejecutando la misma url anterior mencionada con `GET` o usando otros métodos, como `POST` por ejemplo) y, al recibir los datos necesarios desde el `script en javascript` rellenar la web con los resultados correspondientes.
De ésta manera podrías lograr que aun estando llamando a una url externa, la web no se recargue por completo de cara al usuario y que la url permanezca sin cambios.